# "Hello World" failed. Something about Android Emulator went wrong

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just began to learn android. I'm using Windows XP, eclipse indigo JavaEE and its ADT. Then I was trying out [the official Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html). I've created an AVD and paste the code. But when I run the program, problem occured during AVD initialization. Here's the log:

```
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] --------------
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] Android Launch!
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] Performing com.helloworld.HelloworldActivity activity launch
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myAVD'
[2011-11-15 15:53:33 - helloworld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myAVD'
[2011-11-15 15:53:35 - Emulator] NAND: could not write file C:\DOCUME~1\qi\LOCALS~1\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP185.tmp, No space left on device
```

There's plenty spaces in my `C:\` and I was very confused about the `No space left`. And the folder is empty. The number "185" changes if I press "Run" again.

I was using Android 4.0. I've tried restarting, and changing to Android 2.2. None works. I've done this "hello world" on another machine. It worked.

Comment: which properties do you specify when you create a new AVD?

Comment: did you give an SD Card to emulator ?

Comment: i think your emulator storage size can be less

Answer (score 5):

Open AVD manager and Edit your Emulator at which your are working on.
Wipe data and then increase the SD Card size of your Emulator which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've run out of free disk space on volume C: (either that, or the guys who commented the question are right and it's complaining about SD card size).